# how to notifydataset changed properly in listview

Tags: java, android, image, listview, chat

i' m developing chat app in which user can send text messages and also images 
i used listview for this purpose when only text messages are in data set listview shows proper data in proper manner and when user send images, images add in list properly while when i call notify datasetchanged dataset positions change e.g image add at 0 shows at 3 or 4th position

```
package com.exception.chatapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
LayoutInflater inflator;
String imageurl = "http://www.example.com/webservices/";

public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return data.size();
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parentview) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertview == null) {
        convertview = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parentview,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.message = (TextView) convertview
                .findViewById(R.id.txtusermessage);
        holder.userimage = (ImageView) convertview
                .findViewById(R.id.userimage);
        convertview.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
    }
    holder.userimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    HashMap<String, String> map = data.get(position);
    if (!map.get("user_name").equals("me")) {
        if (map.get("type").equals("text")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("message"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_blue);
        } else if (map.get("type").equals("image")) {
            holder.userimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    200,
                    200);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.userimage.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.userimage.requestLayout();
            holder.userimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_blue);
            holder.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(context);
            Log.d("image_url", imageurl + map.get("image_url"));
            loader.DisplayImage(imageurl + map.get("image_url"),
                    holder.userimage);
        } else if (map.get("type").equals("gps")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("lat") + "," + map.get("lng"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_blue);
        }

        else if (map.get("type").equals("contact")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("name") + "\n"
                    + map.get("number"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_blue);
        }
    } else {
        if (map.get("type").equals("text")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("message"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_white);
        } else if (map.get("type").equals("image")) {
            holder.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    200,
                    200);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.userimage.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.userimage.requestLayout();
            holder.userimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_white);


            if (map.get("from") != null) {
                Log.d("image_url",map.get("image_url"));
                holder.userimage
                        .setImageURI(Uri.parse(map.get("image_url")));
            } else {
                ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(context);
                Log.d("image_url", imageurl + map.get("image_url"));
                loader.DisplayImage(imageurl + map.get("image_url"),
                        holder.userimage);
            }

        }

        else if (map.get("type").equals("gps")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("lat") + "," + map.get("lng"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_white);
        } else if (map.get("type").equals("contact")) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.message.requestLayout();
            holder.message.setText(map.get("name") + "\n"
                    + map.get("number"));
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.farhan_white);
        }

    }

    return convertview;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView message;
    ImageView userimage;
}
```

}

here is my listview i set width and height to match_parent while above and below the two layouts in my layout xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chatlayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>
```

on activity result i add images to listview

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data1!=null) {   
        try {

            Uri selectedImage = data1.getData();
            filepath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
            Log.d("path", filepath);
            ChatItem item = new ChatItem();
            item.setUsername("me");
            item.setMessage("");
            item.setType("image");
            item.setImage_uri(filepath);
            item.setFrom("local");
            data.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.smoothScrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);
            message.setText("");
            new UploadFile().execute(filepath, id, rid, "image");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling notifyDatasetChanged and where is the code in which you add the image to your hashmap and then this adapter?

Comment: @Rarw on activity result , add images to listview code is above here

Comment: and the issue is that it adds the image but to the wrong item in the list right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description and the code provided I think the issue is cause by a conflict in the way you use conditions to switch view layouts and some of the internal optimizations present with a `ListView`.

The `ListView` is optimized in such a way that it recycles previously inflated views. This is designed to avoid having to inflate a new layout for each item. This recycling, combined with the logic you're using to select item types - showing and hiding differnt child elements for each item - maybe the cause of this problem as its possible a new view isn't being created when you add a picutre, you're just updating an old one.

What I would do I change the way you switch views for items to such that there are different model object for each type of view - e.g. a message object, an image object, etc. I would then set up my adapter in the following way

```
View v = convertView;
Object o = data.get(position);
LayoutInflaer inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if(o != null){
    if(o instanceof ImageMessage){
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_message);
        }
        createImageMessagView(v, (ImageMessage) o);
    } else if (o instanceOf textMessage){
        // handle different object type
    }
```

where createImageMessageView is where you would find the relevant layout child views by id and set their content.

This approach allows you to use a different layout for each item class. This way, you're not creating one view, storing it in a view holder and then trying to modify its contents later. Rather you're inflating a custom layout, if one doesn't already exist, that is designed to display the content for that item type.

Comment: Thanks I will try this , I think this will be better approach

Answer (score 0):

problem is here

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}
```

i change this to

```
@Override
public ChatItem getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(arg0);
}
```

and my problem is solved but there is another issue

plz dnt use static view holder its causes memory leaks errors